# Firefox mouse event not working

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas

Hello there so I am making a game with canvas and java script and I just recently downloaded and installed it on my computer to test it on Firefox, but the mouse event does not work. Chrome and IE works with the system I'm using but Firefox doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code.

```
game.c.addEventListener( "mousedown", game.mouseClick, false )
 game.mouseClick = function(  ) {
     game.mouseX = event.x;
     game.mouseY = event.y;

     game.mouseX -= game.c.offsetLeft;
     game.mouseY -= game.c.offsetTop;
 }
```

Comment: You're missing the `event` parameter to the function.

Comment: need to know about ` game.c`, can you show more code?

Comment: @SumanBogati Game.c is referencing the canvas element

Answer (score 3):

For Firefox, the event is passed into the function, so your code should read like this:

```
game.c.addEventListener( "mousedown", game.mouseClick, false )
 game.mouseClick = function(event) {

 game.mouseX = event.x;
 game.mouseY = event.y;

 game.mouseX -= game.c.offsetLeft;
 game.mouseY -= game.c.offsetTop;
 }
```

Comment: Still not working for me ):
`var Resize = (function () {
    function Resize() {
        var _this = this;
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) { return _this.mouseMove(e); });
    }
    Resize.prototype.mouseMove = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
    return Resize;
}());
new Resize(name)`